# how to make routing in javascript express

Tags: javascript, mvs

```
const router = require('express').Router()

const songRouter=require("./song");
const labelRouter=require("./label");

router.use('/songs',songRouter);
router.use('/labels',labelRouter);

module.exports=router
```

Comment: "Code only" questions is not good, You should provide an explanation of what you're attempting to accomplish and what difficulties you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Happy coding guys
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const router = require('./router/index.js');

app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true})); // ini middleware
app.use('/',router);



app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Please consider always leaving an explanation to why your answer helps/solves the OP/Your problem.